# Swift 3 - NSCoding without the annoyance of inheriting from NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nscoding

Getting a crash from NSKeyedArchiver

```
2016-10-06 17:06:06.713 MessagesExtension[24473:2175316] *** NSForwarding: 
warning: object 0x61800009d740 of class '' does not implement 
methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[MessagesExtension.Model replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]
```

I have created a protocol called *Coding* that's entire purpose is to simplify *NSCoding* and *NSKeyedArchiver* without the need for using pieces of Objective-C.

```
protocol Coding {
    static var directory: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory { get }
    static var domainMask: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask { get }

    func encode() -> [String: AnyObject]
    init()
    init?(dict: [String: AnyObject]?)
}

extension Coding {
    static var directory: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory {
        return .documentDirectory
    }

    static var domainMask: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask {
        return .userDomainMask
    }

    static var directoryURL: String? {
        return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(Self.directory, Self.domainMask, true).last?.appending("/")
    }

    func save(to path: String) -> Bool {
        guard let url = Self.directoryURL else { return false }

        return NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self.encode() as NSDictionary, toFile: url + path)
    }

    static func create(from path: String) -> Self {
        guard let url = Self.directoryURL,
              let dict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: url + path) as? [String: AnyObject] else { return self.init() }

        return self.init(dict: dict) ?? self.init()
    }
}
```

This protocol and extension is suppose to simplify NSCoding and allow for the protocol to be used on Struts. Yet, I am running into the crash above when attempting to *save* the object.

More specifically, I am getting that crash on the return line of

```
func save(to path: String) -> Bool {
    guard let url = Self.directoryURL else { return false }

    return NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self.encode() as NSDictionary, toFile: url + path)
}
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with NSDictionary but I am unsure how to proceed.

**Any suggestions??**

Comment: You could try having your class implement all of the functions under "Archiving" in https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject but really, `NSCoding` is tightly coupled to `NSObject`

Comment: Why is NSObject bad?

Comment: The goal is to allow structs to be archived. That's not possible if you have to use _NSObject_.

Comment: And this isn't really using _NSCoding_, just the principle to get to NSKeyedArchiver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Foundation archiving system (`NSCoding` and related types) was designed for and implemented in Objective-C a long time ago (parts of it are over 20 years old), and expects "objects" to be instances of `NSObject`. It is simply not realistic to try to use it to encode object graphs containing non-`NSObject`-like objects. You may well be able to simplify its use in Swift, but you're going to need to make sure everything that the archiver thinks is an `NSObject` implements the necessary parts of the `NSObject` API. Since there is no documentation of which parts are used by the archiver, the only sane choice is to subclass `NSObject`.

I could be wrong of course, but you didn't show us the relevant parts of the code (specifically the implementations of `encode`).

Comment: This was my problem. The protocol works as correctly but my implementation of _encode_ was faulty. I was not doing a deep copy of a dictionary correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Vishal S has put together a very nice article on the different ways one can (currently) save data in a structure.

[Archiving and Unarchiving Swift Structure Instances](https://medium.com/sift-through-swift/archiving-and-unarchiving-swift-structure-instances-revisited-7ef6ab447095#.pnqo7fqbu)

or as Vishal put it:

> Swift introduced a tremendous anmount of type-safety. But, archiving and unarchiving always loses the types of the objects. Until a better way comes along to do this by supporting all of Swift’s principles, we should make do with what we have.

Of course one might suggest that the Apple Gurus put a little effort into developing a structure (& type) friendly means of saving your data (!).